# Passing information between js and html parts in electron (atom-shell)

Tags: electron

According to the [tutorial](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md), there are two parts of an electron app - the entry `main.js` file and `index.html`.

1. Do I have to include `main.js` as a script in the html file
2. How do I trigger events in the view html file to affect the state of the js app and vice versa ? How do they both communicate basically ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Client/Server model when using Electron (Atom Shell)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583204/what-is-the-client-server-model-when-using-electron-atom-shell)

Comment: I have voted to close this as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583204/what-is-the-client-server-model-when-using-electron-atom-shell pretty much led me to the answer. They communicate via some IPC mechanism. Smart, keeps everything decoupled and clean (see https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-main-process.md)

Answer (score 6):

You are mixing up a couple of things.

`main.js` is the first file called when your run your application. Before everything else. It does not run any front-end code.

Usually, in it, you create with the `BrowserWindow` API a chromium window, then load an .html file in it. (`index.html` for example).

Then, your `index.html`, you can call for every front JS code you want, or CSS or whatever. For example you can add there a `<script src="myapp.js"></script>`, which will run front-end code.

It is important to understand the difference between the main process (back-end) and the render process (front-end).

See the [quick start guide](http://electron.atom.io/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start/) that explains that very well.