# How to invoke an Electon app, on click event in Mozilla/chrome browser

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, electron

we are building an windows app using Electron js for fingerprint scanner device integration.

Let's say, the user is logged into our web application, want to capture a fingerprint from the logged machine, we have to invoke Electron program to talk to Fingerprint device SDK.

How to trigger an event in electron app?

similar use case 
[What is the Client/Server model when using Electron (Atom Shell)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583204/what-is-the-client-server-model-when-using-electron-atom-shell)

Please correct me, if, I set up electron+node+express in local machine, then on click of a scan button. How to trigger an event in electron app?

Comment: One approach would be to use websockets to communicate between the Electron app and your web app. The socket server could either be online or in your Electron app. But you'd be able to send messages and data back and forth between the two. Check out this library: https://socket.io/

Comment: Also, see this link for info about how you could launch your app from a browser using a custom protocol. https://electronjs.org/docs/all#appsetasdefaultprotocolclientprotocol-path-args-macos-windows